# Can’t see a 1TB WD blue Caviar HDD in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, command-line, format

The HDD appears in BIOS and Windows devices but not in “Disk Manager” so I can get it online, neither with cmd -> diskpart as well.

I also tried reinstalling the new BIOS and software again for the HDD but didn’t help. I haven’t tried yet to format the disk cause I’m not sure how to do it from this PC.

Comment: Do you have a hardware RAID? If so, you need to configure the disk there first.

Comment: "and software again" - Which software exactly?